# eloquent specific $fillable for Model::create() and another $fillable for Model->update()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, php-7.2

I need a way to set the ArticleCategory only on the creation of the Article model and does not changed through the update process using $fillable array. I need to do this with the following in the mind:

1- I want do this through mass assignment
2- I use form request validation for my validation

so is there $fillable array for create and one for update ?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one `fillable` property, so what you want is not possible by default.

But you can use `only` and just retrieve the inputs that you want to update:

From the docs:

> If you need to retrieve a subset of the input data, you may use the
>   only and except methods. Both of these methods accept a single array
>   or a dynamic list of arguments:

```
$input = $request->only('username', 'password');

$input = $request->except(['credit_card']);
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
public function update(UpdateArticleRequest $request, $id)
{
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
    $article->update($request->only('title', 'name'));
}
```

Comment: thanks dear I do the same using the rules() method in my FormRequest class . Add only the desired columns to the rules array and the laravel will only ignore the other fields but I thought there is a better way to put this model related logic in the model

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that but you can consider the following alternative:

Do not put `ArticleCategory` in your `$fillable` array.

Use the following:

```
 $article = new Article($request->all());
 $article->ArticleCategory = $request->input('ArticleCategory');
 $article->save();
```

This way you are explicitly setting the article category when you need to and protecting it from mass assignment.

I think this would be the sensible way to tackle this as (from the sounds of it) `ArticleCategory` should be guarded in general.